# Node - Oracle prepared statement does not bind wildcards

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle, sql-injection, node-oracledb

I have the following code:

```js
     async test() {
        let conn = null;
        try  {
            conn = await this.connect();

            debug("connection!")

            const SQLstatement = `SELECT * FROM :id`

            const table = 'protocol';
            const response = await conn.execute(SQLstatement, {
                id: { dir: oracledb.BIND_IN, val: table , type: oracledb.STRING }
            });
            conn.commit()

            return response;
        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            conn.close();
        }
    }
```

This is a test, it already works with string concats but I have to avoid SQL Injection.

The statement doesn't bind variables, I tried with array expression but not work.

Thanks.

Comment: By concatenate string, SQL Injection is already avoided. ```const table = 'protocol';
    const SQLstatement = 'SELECT * FROM ' + table;
```.

Comment: Oracle binding only works for data, not SQL text. This is an Oracle limitation.  You have to use concatenation after validating the names being appended.